# C# WCF remove result row count node

Tags: c#, wcf

I am quite new to C# and Wcf. I created a project but the results are not listed as expected.

I want to remove the node shown in the image "[0]" (there is only one result set so no need for it).

I am returning Generic.List. Do I need to change the type or is there a WCF directive for this?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered not returning a list but just the element?

Comment: I am trying to trace your steps here. Normally with WCF you create an interface and decorate it with [ServiceContract]. That is the contract for the endpoint of the service. The client uses the same interface. If you use List<AnyClass> in the interface as return type you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a class instead of a list, so that the result returned will be as follows:

[image]